# Adding android-support-v7-appcombat to multi person project

Tags: android, eclipse, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I'm trying to add the android-support-v7-appcompat library to a project that I work on with several others.  I'm using Eclipse with ADT for my IDE setup.  For the time being, Android Studio is not available for us to use (if it were, I would have been past this issue several hours ago! But that is how it is for us unfortunately!).

How do I go about doing this?  I've read (in several places) that I am supposed to import the android-support-v7-appcombat project in Eclipse, build this, and then reference this project in the Android section of the project Properties.

This does work, but I'm wondering how this is supposed to work when I share this project with others - is everyone required to have the android-support-v7-appcompat project setup at the same location as I did in order to have this work?  I was hoping I could include the jar file with my project somehow. And not have it as an external reference... if that makes sense.

For what it's worth, I'm using the appcompat library to use the Toolbar widget and the AppCompat theme for an application I am looking to run on a range of API level devices.

Thanks,

Zach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had recurring problems with external libraries in our company (though, we used other IDE). The problems disappeared when we moved all these libraries to the `libs` directory.

Comment: I have done that just now (moved the .jar file built from the android-support-v7-appcompat project).  I get errors stating:

Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.

Comment: No, move the whole library you use, not only the jar. You reference a module and the jar in the same way you reference it when it's an external library. Just place it in `libs`. Move source codes also.

Comment: Hm, okay.  I misunderstood.  I will try this out in a little bit, stuck in a meeting now.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Okay, so I've added the while library within my libs folder.  Am I supposed to then open this library as a project and reference it from my main project?  This works, but I want to make sure that's the correct way of doing it.  At this point I have the project building, referencing the new library, and the library is included as part of the project.

Is placing it in the libs folder important? Any folder within the project works, right (it is a lib though, so it makes sense to place there, I suppose?)

Comment: Yes, it can be placed in any library within the project. To understand better, you can read this: https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html . "Adding libraries with resources", "Using Eclipse" section.